# Trust relationship windows server 2022

Tags: active-directory, trust, windows-server-2022

I need help regarding trust relationship on Windows server 2022 please. I have two domains A and B, the relationship is unidirectional (A knows B) and in this relationship I have chosen the least restrictive. However, when I connect to A to add B's accounts to groups, this is only possible for groups in the 'Bultin' OU. If I go to 'Users' to add an account in the 'Domain admins' group, I don't see forest A and therefore cannot add the accounts. Have you encountered this problem before? Thank you.

I tried to play with GG and DL, do encapsulation as I saw sometimes during my research. But it didn't work and I would especially like to follow the best practices. I also did not find my solution in the Microsoft documentation.